# access firebase data with models in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, gcc

Hi everyone as i just started to learn dart and flutter and trying to get access data from firebase. I have data in following formats in firebase. Now I want to access this data with the help of model and provider in  dart & flutter. please someone help me to do this. I try multiple times but did not get it.

```
 learnings:[
        {
            science:
        [
            {
                images:['maths1.jpg', 'maths2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'maths.jpg',
                title: 'Maths'
            }, 
            {
                images:['Phy1.jpg', 'Phy2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'Phy.jpg',
                title:'Phy'
    
            },
            {
                images:['Che1.jpg', 'Che2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'Che.jpg',
                title: 'Che'
            }, 
        ]
        },
    
        {
            commerce:
        [
            {
                images:['account1.jpg', 'account2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'account.jpg',
                title: 'Account'
            }, 
            {
                images:['BS1.jpg', 'BS2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'BS.jpg',
                title:'BS'
    
            },
            {
                images:['Eco1.jpg', 'Eco2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'Eco.jpg',
                title: 'Eco'
            }, 
        ]
        },
    
        {
            arts:
        [
            {
                images:['Hindi1.jpg', 'Hindi2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'Hindi.jpg',
                title: 'Hindi'
            }, 
            {
                images:['Eng1.jpg', 'Eng2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'Eng.jpg',
                title:'Eng'
    
            },
            {
                images:['History1.jpg', 'History2.jpg'],
                thumbnail:'History.jpg',
                title: 'History'
            }, 
        ]
        },
        
    ]
```

Comment: If you need assistance, please post the code you've attempted and we'll take a look. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)